# Whats the benefit of using Azure Static Websites vs Blob storage?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am very new to Azure and I would like to host around 8000 static images publicly, upload/replace them programatically.

I see Azure has Blob storage, and now Static Website Hosting.

I have read various articles, but I still don't get what Static Website Hosting brings to the table, compared to a regular Blob storage.

Could someone give me a summary at why Static Website Hosting exists, what benefits it has over a Blob storage and use cases when to pick either the Static Website Hosting compared to a regular Blob hosting?

**Update benefit**

I also found a benefit with Static Website Hosting over regular Blob storage. With static enabled the container `$web` is created. This can have subfolders in it, compared to `$root` which cannot. Meaning, if you have a custom domain (mysubdomain.mydomain.com), you can access files directly without mentioning the container, for example `mysubdomain.mydomain.com/folder1/image.jpg`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have read various articles, but I still don't get what Static
>   Website Hosting brings to the table, compared to a regular Blob
>   storage.

The biggest benefit I see with hosting static websites in Azure Blob Storage is the ability to **define default page** and **404 error page**.

So assuming you have `index.html` as the default page and if you're storing this in a regular blob container, to access it you will have to specify the file name like `https://account.blob.core.windows.net/container/index.html` whereas if you were hosting it as a static website, the page will be accessible as `https://account.z4.web.core.windows.net/`.

Next, for `Not Found (404)` errors, if a blob is not found, you get an ugly error message from Azure Storage saying resource not found. But if you were hosting a static website and a user encounters 404 error, you can display a nice looking error message.

Comment: The other benefit would be that, with blob storage, the default action in a browser is to download the file. Whereas with a static website, the default action is to display it in the browser it self.

Comment: I disagree. It would depend on the content type of the blob. If the content type is text/html, it will display in the browser. However if the content type is something that the browser doesn't understand (e.g. application/octet-stream, which is default content type of a blob BTW), then it will be downloaded.

Comment: I also found a benefit when using custom domains. Ive appended my original question.